# Is a set defined by equations always closed?

Tags: general-topology, lie-groups

I've heard during a lecture that a "*set defined by equations is always closed*". 
The equation was a matricial equation of the type 
$$AA^T=I$$
The lecturer didn't spend more than this sentence on the topic so either is trivial or either is false.

Are there conditions on the cardinality of equations which turn the proposition true or false?

Comment: My answer applies to the matrix equation in particular, as these are just $n^2$ many equalities of linear functions (which are continuous as addition and scalar multiplication are).

Comment: Can you also answer to the second part? I.e.  If A it just was an operator and not necesserely a finite dimension matrix do I have some constriction on cardinality?
It is clear that if I add a more then numerable set of equation the statement doesn't hold...

Comment: It *does* hold for any number of equations. As I said in my answer.

Comment: Let be $Q(x)$ the function that is =1 if x is rational an 0 otherwise then   $\{Q(x)^{-1}=1\}$ is dense in R and open... Must the equation be defined by a continue function for the statement to hold?

Comment: I stated in my answer that the function must be continuous, and your $Q$ is not. And dense does not imply open, BTW.

Comment: So at the end the statement need crucially the equation being originated by a continuos function... ok

Comment: Yes, but in your case your equations are linear. So that will most likely be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, suppose that by equation we mean an expression of the form $f(x) \ge y$, $f(x) \le y$ or $f(x) = y$, where $f$ is some continuous function on the space to the real numbers (for concreteness). Then all such sets are closed, as the inverse image of the continuous $f$ of the closed sets $(-\infty, y], [y, +\infty), \{y\}$ of the reals. And it doesn't matter how many equations we have (for different $f$ or different $y$ etc.), because then we have an intersection of closed sets, and any intersection of closed sets is closed.

Comment: I wouldn't call $f(x) \geq y$ and $f(x) \leq y$ equations, I'd call them inequalities.

Comment: Sure, but it also holds for sets defined by inequalities (if the boundary is included). I wanted to be a bit more general.

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I meant but with few adjustment the argument apply